# Custom tile server - how to create a layer using Mapnik and mod_tile using POSTGIS db

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, openlayers, mapnik, mod-tile

I have created a Ubuntu 14.04 tile server.
I loaded an OSM base map into the POSTGIS database and created a slippy-map using OpenLayers 3.9.
Then I loaded data of an overlay into the POSTGIS database and now I am trying to create a layer for it.

To create layers, the only solution with decent documentation seems to be Tilemill. 
But to use Tilemill on my server I have to use "SSH connection forwarding", explained [here](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/ubuntu-service/#ssh-connection-forwarding).
I don't want to create a security leak into my server.

Are there any other options, with decent documentation, with which I can create custom layers for my map?

What I already 'know':

- Create a simple map with Mapnik
- Store shape files into the POSTGIS database
- Use OpenLayers to display the layer

What I need to know:
I have a simple overlay (created with Mapnik):
[image]

This overlay has to be rendered into different tiles and have zoom levels, just like a OSM base map. I want to use this overlay and put it over an area on my OSM-tiled map.

What do I need to be able to create a layer that can be displayed with OpenLayers like:
url: '/overlay/{x}/{y}/{z}'?

Comment: Noone that can help me on my way?

Comment: any success with your tiling? I need to achieve more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [page](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) has an awesome tutorial on how to create a complete Tile server using the stack Mod_tile, renderd, mapnik, osm2pgsql, and a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database.

If you already have a style created by the Tilemill you can export to the Mapnik format and use it to generate your tiles and render with frameworks like OpenLayers and Leaflet.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I already used this guide to create a tile server, and it works great. What I don't know is how to exactly use these components with my own custom data..

Comment: Where's your custom data? In a postgis database?

Comment: Yes, I receive a shape-file that I insert into the POSTgis database.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you already imported the shapefile to a postgis database, you created a style with the tilemill tool, you exported to a mapnik.xml file and also used the guide to create a tile server using the created mapnik style.
Where's your problem? With a running tile server you can simply call the desired URL: '/overlay/{x}/{y}/{z}

Comment: You misread the use of Tilemill. I cannot use Tilemill because I don't understand their documentation on how to use Tilemill on a Ubuntu server without a terminal. So I don't have a xml for my data yet..

Comment: I'm sorry, now I understand you question...
Why you don't use the Tilemill locally and connect in your database in your server?

Comment: That might be a solution! Ill try that and let you know :D

Comment: great!  i needed this info.

Comment: The tutorial link is 404. Any ideas?